# What is async subscribed to since heroes does not contain observable?

Tags: angular

In learning Angular >= 2, I am trying to find the subscriber to `search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {}` which populates the template `<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"`:

From [angular-tour-of-heroes](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes)

```
<div id="search-component">
  <h4>Hero Search</h4>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"
         (click)="gotoDetail(hero)" class="search-result" >
      {{hero.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

HeroSearchService:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(`app/heroes/?name=${term}`)
      .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Hero[])
      .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('An friendly error occurred', error);
          return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
      });
  }
```

---

In the heroes.component.ts, I found the component binding `heroes: Hero[];` but it does not contain the observable returned from `search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {}` in `HeroSearchService`.

I understand that `async` takes care of the subscription to the observable. But here, `heroes` does not contain the observable for async to work off of.

How is `heroes` being populated by `search()` since `heroes` is not a does not contain the observable that `search()` returns? Or a another way to ask, what is async subscribed to since the `heroes` binding does not have the observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking at the templates for the wrong files. The template that you're looking at is `hero-search.component.html`, which corresponds to the file `hero-search.component.ts` that defines `heroes` as an array of observables:

**hero-search.component.ts**

```
heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
```

The template for `heroes.component.ts` is `heroes.component.html`, which does not use `async` as `heroes` is not an Observable in this component:

**heroes.component.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
  <span class="hero-element">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </span>
  <button class="delete-button" (click)="deleteHero(hero, $event)">Delete</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that. I thought `heroes` was being inherited by hero parent component.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [angular-tour-of-heroes](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes) link, I observed that the `search` method in `HeroSearchService` is called by `hero-search.component.ts` (not by `heroes.component.ts`) & it has observable heroes property as `heroes: Observable<Hero[]>`which is as expected.

I think you got confused between `hero-search.component.ts` & `heroes.component.ts`.